# Grid.Mvc filter for datetime field

Tags: vb.net, grid.mvc

I am implementing grid.mvc. I am almost done without one thing. For my column named "DTTM" i have standard filter, but i would like to have caledanr that i could put equal to some date, less/greater or betwen for my field DTTM. Can you help me out what i am missing? Note that i have grid.mvc.datepicker reference as well.

this is my current code:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Named("grdGrid").Sortable(True).Columns(Function(col) col.Add(Function(o) o.Id)).Columns(Function(col) col.Add(Function(o) o.DTTM, "Date").Titled("Date").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}")).Columns(Function(col) col.Add(Function(o) o.MessageType)).Columns(Function(col) col.Add(Function(o) o.Service)).Columns(Function(col) col.Add(Function(o) o.Level)).Columns(Function(col) col.Add(Function(o) o.Message)).WithPaging(15).Sortable(True).Filterable(True).WithMultipleFilters()
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this post:-
[Date filter not working in gridmvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623548/date-filter-not-working-in-gridmvc/30817939#30817939)

Specify the format for the date column and add desired js and css files.