# MVC.Grid Filter - Date Window/Calendar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid.mvc

I'm using MVC.Grid to populate a table & everything is working nicely. However for the date column I would like to click on the filter icon & have a date window to select form instead of the standard equals/contains option. Anyone done this?

FYI - I'm also using bootstrap 3.1 & MVC 5.2.

screenshot of current column filter:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post. You need to add a library for datepicker and add the proper css to the code. 
[Date Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623548/date-filter-not-working-in-gridmvc)

Comment: So I have the scripts & css loaded on the page but still no dice.

When I go into the browser/compiled html. If I manually add type="date" to the text input field it shows & works. Is there a way to add the type="date" into the Grid columns.add?

This:
<input class="mvc-grid-value" data-filter="first">

To: 
<input class="mvc-grid-value" data-filter="first" type="date">